# OnSuspending event fired during app initialization while minimized

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-11

I have a UWP app that is configured to auto start at Windows boot via the Startup Apps on Windows 11.
On some PCs - and it is unclear for what configurations - the app starts minimized at Windows boot, and receives a OnSuspending event while it is still initializing (during or just after the OnNavigatedTo event, and before the OnLaunched event). This OnSuspending event breaks the initialization sequence of the app which keeps running but fails to execute its task.

So a successful sequence of events looks like:

1. OnActivated
2. OnNavigatedTo
3. OnBackgroundActivated

A failing sequence looks like:

1. OnActivated
2. OnNavigatedTo
3. OnSuspending
4. OnBackgroundActivated

I can't see on my code any logic error that would lead to this OnSuspending event. Is there a possibility that Windows sends this event out of the blue at this boot time, maybe depending on other processes being started at the same time? Or should I look further in my code for any error that leads to this suspension?

Answer (score 2):

> OnSuspending event fired during app initialization while minimized

It's by default, please refer to `StartupTask` [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.startuptask?view=winrt-22000#remarks)  *If the user consents, the UWP app will then start on startup or user log in. Note that UWP startup apps will start **minimized**.* when app minimized, the `OnSuspending` will be called (by design). if this behavior cause app initialization fail, please take care of `OnSuspending` event, and saving necessary application state.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually the app always starts minimized, however it received the OnSuspending event only like 1% of the times, which breaks the initialization sequence. I am looking for the possible causes for when this event fires.

Comment: Yep, I can reproduce your problem, does OnSuspending make your app crash?

Comment: And have you processed current `OnActivated` method?

Comment: Well, we receive the OnActivated event and enter the OnActivated method. While in this method, we call a number of initialization procedures and we receive the OnSuspending event before we complete the OnActivated method.
The OnSuspending event does not make our app crash but getting it soo quickly before we have fully initalized the app breaks some logic in the app and it won't be fully operational after that.

Comment: well, please post this problem with windows feed backhub, for current scenario, you may try  to initialize the data  in the app's constructor method.